# Question on proof of Theorem 24.8 of Abstract Algebra by Saracino

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

My question is about a detail in the proof of Theorem 24.8 in Abstract Alebra by Saracino. Here's the theorem (the part where I have a question on is underlined in red):

[image]

Why does $E = F(a_1,...,a_k)$ imply that $\varphi(E) \subseteq E$?

My intuition is that we can obtain a basis for $E$ over $F$ in terms of powers of the $a_i$'s, with coefficients from $F$, and then show that when $\varphi$ is applied to any linear combination of powers of the $a_i$'s with coefficients from $F$, we get an element in $E$. Is this the right idea? Or is there a simpler way?

One problem with my idea is that I don't know how to write a basis for $E$ over $F$ explicitly in terms of $a_1,...,a_k$. Is there a formula for a basis of $E$ over $F$ that I could use, or would that be more tedious than its worth?

Comment: What is $K$ in this case? Any field extension of $E?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes

Comment: Any member of $E$ is a rational function of roots $a_i$ with coefficients in $F$ (that's the meaning of $E=F(a_1,\dots,a_k)$). Applying $\phi$ on a member leaves the coefficients fixed and permutes the roots $a_i$ (note $\phi(a_i) =a_j$) so that the resulting expression is again a rational function of roots and thus lies in $E$. It is better to express the symbolism in natural language to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Thanks for your comment. I understand that $\{\varphi(a_1),\ldots, \varphi(a_k) \}$ is a permutation of $\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$.  My textbook's definition of $F(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$ is that it's the intersection of all extensions of $F$ containing $a_1,\ldots,a_k$. So I presume that these two definitions are equivalent?

Comment: @Leonidas: yes those two are equivalent and you can see why it is so. Any field which contains $F$ and $a_i$'s must contain every rational function of these roots with coefficients in $F$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Thanks, I understand it now!

Answer (score 2):

If $E=F(a_1,\ldots a_k)$ then $\varphi(E) = F(\varphi(a_1), \ldots, \varphi(a_k))$. As $\varphi(a_j) = a_i$ for some $a_1 \in \{a_1,\ldots, a_k)$, this gives $\{\varphi(a_1), \varphi(a_2), \ldots, \varphi(a_k) \}$
$\subseteq$ $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_k\}$ which in turn gives
$$\varphi(E) = F(\varphi(a_1), \ldots, \varphi(a_k)) \subseteq F(a_1,\ldots, a_k) = E,$$ which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  How did you get $\varphi(E) = F(\varphi(a_1),...,\varphi(a_k))$?  Also, my understanding is that $\{\varphi(a_1),\ldots,\varphi(a_k) \}$ is just a permutation of $\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$, so shouldn't the two $\subseteq$'s actually be $=$ signs?

Comment: Let $p(a_1,a_2\ldots, a_k)  \in E$, where $p$ is a multivariate polynomial and $a_1,a_2, \ldots$ are as abovr. Then $\varphi(p(a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_k))$ $= p(\varphi(a_1), \varphi(a_2), \ldots \varphi(a_k))$.

Comment: Yes it is infact $=$ but $\subseteq$ suffices here.

Comment: In your second to last comment, are you using the fact that every element of $E$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $a_1,\ldots,a_k$? (I've learned this fact for $F(a)$, but not the multivariate case.)

Comment: well yes, this has already been established about $E$ in the first line of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

$\varphi(E)\subset E$, not only because $e=F(a_1,\dots ,a_k)$, burt because we also have $\varphi(a_i)=a_j$ for some $j$, so that any element $\frac{f(a_1,\dots, a_k)}{g(a_1,\dots, a_k)}$ is transformed into the value of the same rational fraction after a permutation of $a_1,\dots, a_k$, which is also an element of $E$.

Comment: Hmm, so any element of $\varphi(E)$ can be expressed in the form $\frac{f(a_1,\ldots,a_k)}{g(a_1,\ldots,a_k)}$, where $f$ and $g$ are polynomials in $a_1,\ldots,a_k$?

Comment: Any element of $E$ can be expressed that way. Of course, if the extension is separable, it simplifies to ‘every element of $E$ is a polynomial in a single root’, by the theorem of the primitive element.

Comment: Or rather, any element of $E$ can be expressed as a rational polynomial in $a_1,\ldots,a_k$, and when $\varphi$ is applied to that rational poly, it's still an element in $E$? 

I just realized that Theorem 22.1 of Saracino applies here: $F(a) = \{g(a)/h(a) | g(X), h(X) \in F[X], h(a) \neq 0 \}$. So it looks like you're using a generalization of this result for polynomials in $k$ variables.

Comment: This theorem looks like the theorem of the primitive element. But in general, when we say that an extension is generated by elements $a_1,\dots,a_k$, it means that every element of this extension is a rational function in $a_1,\dots,a_k$.